# How can I determine what type of location event I receive from my subscription?

Tags: ibm-cloud, presenceinsights

I am using IBM Presence Insights to track locations of my users and send them location based alerts. I know that I can set up a Subscription to POST to an endpoint that I control to receive location based events (enter/exit/dwell.) I also see that I can set a subscription to only respond to certain types of events. However, I want my subscription to send a POST for every type of event, and then filter these events on my backend.

How can I determine if a subscription event is an enter/exit/dwell event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body sent in the post to your web hook url will contain a property "activity" in it.
This will be one of the following strings:

- 'enter'
- 'exit'
- 'dwell'